# onchange for select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey i need help in this i am new in java script.. i am trying to create options for user where when they select an option it will display a pop up message of what they selected but without a submit button for example when i select red it will display you selected red and if i select red and blue it will display you have selected red and blue

This is the script

```
  $('#deneme').change(function(){ 

if($(this).val()=="Value1"){

    alert(you have selected red)
}
else if($(this).val()=="Value2"){

    alert(you have selected Green)                   
}

 else if($(this).val()=="Value3"){

    alert(you have selected blue)                   
}

 else if($(this).val()=="Value1"   && $(this).val()=="Value3"){

    alert(you have selected blue and red)                   
}

})
```

this is the html

```
  <select id="deneme">
<option val='Value1'>Red</option>
<option val='Value2'>Green</option>
```

```
<select id="deneme">
<option val='Value3'>Blue</option>
<option val='Value3'>Green</option>
```

thank you

Comment: Don't use duplicate IDs...

Comment: select options are not in correct way. change options and re-post the question

Answer (score 0):

Simply use it onchnage function ,

```
var dropdown = $("#denane option:selected");
var selected_value = dropdown.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/j5AGy/))

```
<select id="deneme">
    <option val='Value1'>Red</option>
    <option val='Value2'>Green</option>
    <option val='Value3'>Blue</option>
</select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#deneme").change(function(){
        var opt = $(this).find("option:selected");
        alert("You have selected " + opt.text());
    })
});
```